# What is seeming wrong in my Main.class? That when I start it it gives me an error without saying me from which programm it was caused by

Tags: java, bukkit

I am programming a Java Plugin for Bukkit.
I am nearly finished but now the console gives me an error without a reason... Im am programming with Bukkit now for 1 year with Java i got 2 years of experience but i cant really imagine what should the problem be here...
Here it is:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at de.master.lobby.Main.loadStrings(Main.java:893) ~[?:?]
    at de.master.lobby.Main.onEnable(Main.java:314) ~[?:?]
    at org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin.setEnabled(JavaPlugin.java:321) ~[spigot-1.8.8-R0.1-SNAPSHOT-latest.jar:git-Spigot-db6de12-18fbb24]
    at org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPluginLoader.enablePlugin(JavaPluginLoader.java:340) [spigot-1.8.8-R0.1-SNAPSHOT-latest.jar:git-Spigot-db6de12-18fbb24]
    at org.bukkit.plugin.SimplePluginManager.enablePlugin(SimplePluginManager.java:405) [spigot-1.8.8-R0.1-SNAPSHOT-latest.jar:git-Spigot-db6de12-18fbb24]
    at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_8_R3.CraftServer.loadPlugin(CraftServer.java:357) [spigot-1.8.8-R0.1-SNAPSHOT-latest.jar:git-Spigot-db6de12-18fbb24]
    at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_8_R3.CraftServer.enablePlugins(CraftServer.java:317) [spigot-1.8.8-R0.1-SNAPSHOT-latest.jar:git-Spigot-db6de12-18fbb24]
    at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_8_R3.CraftServer.reload(CraftServer.java:741) [spigot-1.8.8-R0.1-SNAPSHOT-latest.jar:git-Spigot-db6de12-18fbb24]
    at org.bukkit.Bukkit.reload(Bukkit.java:535) [spigot-1.8.8-R0.1-SNAPSHOT-latest.jar:git-Spigot-db6de12-18fbb24]
    at org.bukkit.command.defaults.ReloadCommand.execute(ReloadCommand.java:25) [spigot-1.8.8-R0.1-SNAPSHOT-latest.jar:git-Spigot-db6de12-18fbb24]
    at org.bukkit.command.SimpleCommandMap.dispatch(SimpleCommandMap.java:141) [spigot-1.8.8-R0.1-SNAPSHOT-latest.jar:git-Spigot-db6de12-18fbb24]
    at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_8_R3.CraftServer.dispatchCommand(CraftServer.java:641) [spigot-1.8.8-R0.1-SNAPSHOT-latest.jar:git-Spigot-db6de12-18fbb24]
    at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_8_R3.CraftServer.dispatchServerCommand(CraftServer.java:627) [spigot-1.8.8-R0.1-SNAPSHOT-latest.jar:git-Spigot-db6de12-18fbb24]
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R3.DedicatedServer.aO(DedicatedServer.java:412) [spigot-1.8.8-R0.1-SNAPSHOT-latest.jar:git-Spigot-db6de12-18fbb24]
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R3.DedicatedServer.B(DedicatedServer.java:375) [spigot-1.8.8-R0.1-SNAPSHOT-latest.jar:git-Spigot-db6de12-18fbb24]
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R3.MinecraftServer.A(MinecraftServer.java:654) [spigot-1.8.8-R0.1-SNAPSHOT-latest.jar:git-Spigot-db6de12-18fbb24]
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R3.MinecraftServer.run(MinecraftServer.java:557) [spigot-1.8.8-R0.1-SNAPSHOT-latest.jar:git-Spigot-db6de12-18fbb24]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_191]
```

My main doesnt seem to have any errors...

These are the lines from 309 to 335:
It is my main.class..

```
public void onEnable() {
    instance = this;

    loadConfig();
    loadStrings();
    loadCommands();
    loadEvents();

    Bukkit.getMessenger().registerOutgoingPluginChannel(this, "BungeeCord");

    Bukkit.getConsoleSender().sendMessage("§7-------------==+==-------------");
    Bukkit.getConsoleSender().sendMessage("§cPlugin version: §e0.2.5");
    Bukkit.getConsoleSender().sendMessage("§cPlugin author: §eMasterphoenix");
    Bukkit.getConsoleSender().sendMessage("§cPlugin status: §aaktiviert");
    Bukkit.getConsoleSender().sendMessage("§7-------------==+==-------------");

    if (LocationAPI.getLocation("spawn") != null) {
        Location spawn = LocationAPI.getLocation("spawn");

        spawn.getWorld().setTime(6000);
        spawn.getWorld().setGameRuleValue("doDaylightCircle", "false");
        spawn.getWorld().setGameRuleValue("doMobSpawning", "false");
    }

    methAutoMessengerScheduler.startCountdown();
}
```

And this the lines from 873 to 902

```
rankownertab = getConfig().getString("rank.owner.tab").replaceAll("&", "§");
    rankowner = getConfig().getString("rank.owner.chat").replaceAll("&", "§");
    rankmanagertab = getConfig().getString("rank.manager.tab").replaceAll("&", "§");
    rankmanager = getConfig().getString("rank.manager.chat").replaceAll("&", "§");
    rankheaddevtab = getConfig().getString("rank.headdev.tab").replaceAll("&", "§");
    rankheaddev = getConfig().getString("rank.headdev.chat").replaceAll("&", "§");
    rankdevtab = getConfig().getString("rank.dev.tab").replaceAll("&", "§");
    rankdev = getConfig().getString("rank.dev.chat").replaceAll("&", "§");
    ranksrmodtab = getConfig().getString("rank.srmod.tab").replaceAll("&", "§");
    ranksrmod = getConfig().getString("rank.srmod.chat").replaceAll("&", "§");
    rankmodtab = getConfig().getString("rank.mod.tab").replaceAll("&", "§");
    rankmod = getConfig().getString("rank.mod.chat").replaceAll("&", "§");
    ranksuptab = getConfig().getString("rank.supporter.tab").replaceAll("&", "§");
    ranksup = getConfig().getString("rank.supporter.chat").replaceAll("&", "§");
    rankbuildertab = getConfig().getString("rank.builder.tab").replaceAll("&", "§");
    rankbuilder = getConfig().getString("rank.builder.chat").replaceAll("&", "§");
    rankyoutubertab = getConfig().getString("rank.youtuber.tab").replaceAll("&", "§");
    rankyoutuber = getConfig().getString("rank.youtuber.chat").replaceAll("&", "§");
    rankjryoutubertab = getConfig().getString("rank.jryoutuber.tab").replaceAll("&", "§");
    rankjryoutuber = getConfig().getString("rank.jryoutuber.chat").replaceAll("&", "§");
    rankplatinumtab = getConfig().getString("rank.platinum.tab").replaceAll("&", "§");
    rankplatinum = getConfig().getString("rank.platinum.chat").replaceAll("&", "§");
    rankmaster = getConfig().getString("rank.master.tab").replaceAll("&", "§");
    rankmaster = getConfig().getString("rank.master.chat").replaceAll("&", "§");
    rankprogamer = getConfig().getString("rank.progamer.tab").replaceAll("&", "§");
    rankprogamer = getConfig().getString("rank.progamer.chat").replaceAll("&", "§");
    rankgamer = getConfig().getString("rank.gamer.tab").replaceAll("&", "§");
    rankgamer = getConfig().getString("rank.gamer.chat").replaceAll("&", "§");
    rankspielertab = getConfig().getString("rank.spieler.tab").replaceAll("&", "§");
    rankspieler = getConfig().getString("rank.spieler.chat").replaceAll("&", "§");
```

When you can solve the problem please say me the details how to fix it, because i dont think that there is any problem in 873 to 902....

Comment: You have a `NullPointerException` which seems to originating from `de.master.lobby.Main.loadStrings(Main.java:893)`, but you've not provided enough context for anyone to debug it for you

Answer (score -1):

if i am in the good line, rank.jryoutuber.chat is not present in your config

Comment: Well it is [link](http://prntscr.com/lv2ws2)

Comment: If I can count correctly,  `rank.platinum.tab` is the thing that's not present in the config.

Comment: @masterphoenix, could you post all the file?

Comment: Thank you Mark, I had to rename Platinum in the config. :D

Answer (score -1):

I just had to rename the Platinum group in my Config.yml.
Thanks to @Mark.